# .where vs find. ActiveRecord::Relation NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm new to rails and this might seem obvious, but couldn't find a answer.

when i do

```
u = User.where("email=?", email_string)
u.name = "new name"
```

doesn't work i keep getting

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x1049c2890>
```

but if i change

```
u = User.where("email=?", email_string)
```

**to**

```
u = User.find_by_email(email_string)
```

i can see my changes being persisted and no error thrown.

So what am i missing. is it that **.where** returns a read only object or something ?

Comment: no experience of this technology at all, but my guess is that `where` is returning a collection/array where as `find_by_email` returns a single record?

Answer (score 17):

.where is actually a scope and indeed returns a collection of Users and not a single one. You can obtain the first matching user (as .find_by_email does) with

```
User.where('email = ?', email_string).first
```

Additionally, you can return a collection with

```
User.find_all_by_email(email_string)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know this question is specifically for rails-3, but for anyone trying this on rails-4 etc, the dynamic finder `find_all_by_...` has been deprecated and the new syntax is `find_by email: 'email_string'` https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders