# Rails 3: Reload partial with second level association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

My Application structure is as follows:

```
class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :topics

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :references
```

I need to access the references on the show page of my Study model (study.topic.references). However, I need to retrieve references based on (say) radio button selection of topics. So when the user clicks on a topic, I need to retrieve that particular topic's references via AJAX.

Therefore, I wrote the following method in my Study model:

```
class Study < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.topic_references(topic_id)
  Reference.where(:topic_id => topic_id)
end
```

I access the above method in my Study controller Show as follows:

```
class StudiesController < ApplicationController
   @references= Study.topic_references(params[:topic_id])
```

And I plan to have an remote form that will access the above method and retrieve the corresponding references. Something like this:

```
  - form_tag topic_references, :id=>"references_form", :method => 'get' do               
    = text_field_tag :topic_id, params[:topic_id], :value=>268
    = submit_tag "Get references"
```

As an initial test I am passing the value of topic ID (268 value above) however, the @references when accessed in the view is still empty. Kindly help me in understand what am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try to use `params[:references_form][:topic_id]` instead of `params[:topic_id]`

Comment: @kishie, that gave me:
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!

You might have expected an instance of Array.

The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

Comment: does it happens after submitting your form? put `if params[:references_form]` after `params[:references_form][:topic_id]`

Comment: @kishie, where do you propose this to be used? I used the above on my controller as @references= Study.topic_references(params[:references_form][:topic_id])

Comment: Use `Study.topic_references(params[:references_form][:topic_id]) if params[:references_form]`

Comment: @kishie, could you please tell me why this would help? I tried it but still weren't able to retrieve the references.
What I need help in is understanding how to *pass the params to this method in my controller*.

Comment: can you please post your params from log when you submit your form.

Comment: The `form_tag` helper has parameter `:url` so if you put `:url => some_url` all your submitting data you can process at action which corresponds to `some_url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown your view code, but I am guessing that it is because `where` is returning a collection of objects rather than a single object, as discussed here:

[.where vs find. ActiveRecord::Relation NoMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442791/where-vs-find-activerecordrelation-nomethoderror)

In the console, it's easy to miss the brackets in output like `[#<Reference id...]` while debugging these kinds of problems.

Comment: My problem is the params are not passing to the method. I need help in understanding whether my form is correctly pointing towards the method or not. (which it is obviously not because I get a wrong number of arguments error)

Comment: helped me reach the resolution.